# Making an SQL query that finds All pairs of cities located in the same country

Tags: sql

I have a table `city` with the attributes `name` and `country` and I have to write an sql query that outputs all cities with the same country. So things like `Tokyo | Osaka` and `Osaka | Tokyo` I have tried several different conditions at the end of `SELECT c.name, c.country FROM city c WHERE ...` but I just cant seem to get it.

Comment: Hint:  You need a self join.

Comment: Just join on country code to itself. Because where works on single row level

Comment: with what condition though, I just don't understand it

Comment: Obviously on equality of countries

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple self join. Should look something like:

```
select
  a.country, 
  a.name as city1, 
  b.name as city2
from city a 
join city b on a.country = b.country and a.name < b.name
```

Notice that the table `city` shows up twice (with different aliases) so you can pair cities. The `ON` clause specifies how you want to pair them: "same country, different names".

Also, notice I compared using `<` to ensure that each pair doesn't show up twice (anverse + reverse). If you want both, just use `<>` instead.